# I have an array and I want to input a range , and then find the sum of all even numbers in the range?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, math

> The array is given in the code , My input is two numbers like `2, 7` and between the second and seventh element of the array the code needs to find the sum of all even numbers .How do I do this ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int S, n1, n2;
    cont int n = 8;
    int found = 0;

    cout << "Enter the beginning of a range: ";
    cin >> n1;

    cout << "Enter the end of a range: ";
    cin >> n2;

    int a[] = {1, 5, 9, 6, 2, 7, 4, 3};

    int i;
    for(i = 0;i <= n; i++){
        if(a[i] % 2 == 0){
        S = S + a[i];
        found = 1;
        }
    }
    if(found == 1){
        cout << "Even numbers found" << " " << "Sum: " << S <<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Even numbers not found" <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i = 0;i <= n; i++` -> `i = n1;i <= n2; i++` ? (maybe `<` for open-close range).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to sum the numbers between start and end you need to change your loop to use the values you input. Change it to this:

```
for(int i = n1; i <= n2; i++){
    if(a[i] % 2 == 0){
        S = S + a[i];
        found = 1;
    }
}
```

Also, remove the line `cont int n = 8;` which isn't needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int S, n1, n2;
    cont int n = 8; 
    int found = 0;
    cout << "Enter the beginning of a range: ";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "Enter the end of a range: ";
    cin >> n2;
    int a[] = { 1, 5, 9, 6, 2, 7, 4, 3 };
    int i;
    for (; n1 <= n2; n1++)
    {
        if (a[n1] % 2 == 0)
        {
            S = S + a[n1];
            found = 1;
        }
    }
    if (found == 1)
    {
        cout << "Even numbers found" << " " << "Sum: " << S << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Even numbers not found" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend completing this answer with an explanation of what you changed. Right now you have a code-only answer that can be copy-pasted without learning anything.

Comment: I have changed the loop index to be n1 and incremented it up to n2.

Comment: Mark the line  in the code with a comment. The explanation's pretty short, so you can probably get away with explaining the change and why you made it as a comment in the code.